# Optimising Jquery Code - Linking tabs in different containers

Tags: jquery, optimization, css-selectors

I am working on a new project and the html does not allow me to have the tab headers and content within the same container. Therefore I have used Jquery and its nth child selector to enable and disable each tab. I have put together an example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QdbdT/1/

This is the javascript

```
$(".control-bar-nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(1)").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-wrapper-container > div:nth-child(1)").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
$(".control-bar-nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2)").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-wrapper-container > div:nth-child(2)").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
$(".control-bar-nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(3)").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-wrapper-container > div:nth-child(3)").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
$(".control-bar-nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(4)").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-wrapper-container > div:nth-child(4)").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

This does work, but i cant help that feel that there maybe a more efficient way of coding it. I thought that maybe some type of indexing would help but I could not get my head around it. If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it, cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) in your example to achieve the same effect and to combine all the functions

```
$(".control-bar-nav-wrapper ul li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".slider-wrapper-container > div").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/VSvVT/)

Comment: oops you are quick. i had same answer to this. Great answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Cut my code down a lot! I feel that the use of index does make the code a lot more efficient. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a `data attribute` to allow you to map between the clicked element and the container element. Although, it doesn't seem the most elegant, it does help in the readability department.

**CSS**

```
<li class="applications active" data-display='Applications'>
       <a href="#">Applications</a>
</li>
<li class="communities" data-display='Communities'>
       <a href="#">Communities</a>
</li>
<li class="friends" data-display='Friends'>
       <a href="#">Friends</a>
</li>
<li class="administration" data-display='Administration'>
        <a href="#">Administration</a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[data-display]').on('click',function()
{
      $('.slider-wrapper').removeClass('active');
      $('#' + $(this).attr('data-display')).addClass('active');                              
});​
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QdbdT/2/)**